# get the specific index of element in the array

Tags: javascript

I have a list of different units:

```
const unitList = [1, 10, 36, 50, 20]; // all different numbers and all numbers are above 0
const unit = 13; // this is not included in unitList and not more that max number in unitList
```

And I want to get the index of unit in which `unit` should be placed before. for instance:

`const unit = 13;` returns index `4` because it should be placed before `20`

`const unit = 35;` returns index `2` because it should be placed before `36`

```js
function getUnitPosition() {

            if(!unitList.length) return 'before add new unit';
            const max = Math.max(...unitList);
            if(unit > max) return 'before add new unit';
            const min = Math.min(...unitList);
            if(unit < min) return columns[0].id;

            for(let a = 0; a < unitList.length; a++) {
                console.log(unit ,  unitList[a], unit < unitList[a])
                if(unit < unitList[a]) return columns[a].id; 
            }
}
```

Comment: please add your code. what goes wrong?

Comment: I added my code, it doesn't work...

Comment: What exactly does not work? What have you found out using your debugger? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: looks like you are looking for a smallest number in the array which is bigger than the given number, and your array is not sorted, you need to iterate entire array.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the first found index with a smaller value than `unit`. For any other smaller value check the value to get the smallest one.

```js
const
    getIndex = (data, unit) => {
        let index;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (
                unit < data[i] &&
                (index === undefined || data[i] < data[index])
            ) index = i;
        }
        return index;
    },
    unitList = [1, 10, 36, 50, 20];
    // 13                      ^^
    // 35              ^^      
    
console.log(getIndex(unitList, 13)); // 4 placed before 20
console.log(getIndex(unitList, 35)); // 2 placed before 36
```